# How to make two fields required based on the value of another non empty input field

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery.
I have to create a required field validating based on another non-empty field.
Currently I have three fields - Country code , state code and residence.

AAA) If the residence number is **not empty** and the state code and country code is empty, it should show an error. This currently works for one field, but not the other field. How can I get working for the other field as well.

Code -

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log("Hello1");
$("#step1").validate({   
       rules: {
        countrycode1: {
            required: {
        depends: function(element){
            return $("#residence").val()!="";
console.log("Hello5");
        }
    }
        }           
    }

});
});</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="step1" action="#" method="post">
    <label>Country Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="countrycode1" name="countrycode1" value="91"/>
</br>
    <label>Std Code</label>
    <input type="text" name="stdcode" id="stdcode" value="80"/>
</br>
    <label>Residence</label>
    <input type="text" name="residence" id="residence" />
</br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="next step" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rUyAx/8/)

Answer (score 1):

use this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankchaturvedi/DS38J/2/)

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){

if($('#residence').val()!='')
{

    if($('#countrycode1').val()!="91" && $('#countrycode1').val()!='')
    {

       if($('#stdcode').val()=="80" ||$('#stdcode').val()=='')
       {

          $('#stdcode').next().text( "this Field is Required" );

       }
    }else if($('#stdcode').val()!="80" && $('#stdcode').val()!='')
    {
       if($('#countrycode1').val()=="91" ||$('#countrycode1').val()=='')
       {
           $('#countrycode1').next().text( "this Field is Required" );
       }
    }


}

});
```

Comment: You have reversed the requirement. I want to display the message- "This field is required " when the other field is empty

Answer (score 0):

You've only set rules for the one field. You'll need to have another property on rules for stdcode.

Comment: But it isn't working if I set one. Can you help me with the fiddle